# How to create a .PCM file from sound wave values?

Tags: arduino, wav, pcm

Probably I'm a bit lost, so I want to expose my problem and I really appreciate anyone who can help me.

I'm working on a project that uses a Microphone in Arduino, and I'm able to get the wave of the sound and it's responding ok to my voice or any other sound. 
The microphone is a generic one called LM393 (I couldn't find any datasheet specifying the frequency of sample rate of this device) and the schematic looks this way (the only difference is that I'm wiring the OUT to analog A0):
[image]

[image]

And this simple code is the one I'm using in Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial connection(10,11);
int microphonePin = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(microphonePin, INPUT);
  connection.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  int response = analogRead(microphonePin);  
  Serial.println(response);
  connection.print(String(response) + " ");
  delay(1);  
}
```

**A few comments:**
The analog A0 responds a value between 0...1023 (bit per sample is 10?)

As you can see, I'm sending every value that I get from the microphone over bluetooth (by using HC-05 module) and I'm receiving those values on a .NET Winforms application.

Those values look like this on my .NET side:

```
168 4 0 271 0 297 0 9 611 0 124 0 0 331 0 637 0 231 0 2 53 0 139 0 611 38 63 23 38 1 20 68 0 3 1 375 4 04 374 574 69
```

I searched all the net trying to find and example about how data should be presented and I can't figure it out. Should I convert those int's to binary considering that the **bits per sample** are 10 (0..1023)?

My main objetive here is to record the sound of my voice. 
So my question is, **how can I convert those int's to a PCM file or even better a .wav file**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

audio is just a curve however above plot is not an audio curve ... silence is just a flat line, greater volume naturally gives you wobbles with increased height ... in order to capture audio accurately you must sample the audio signal at least twice the rate of the highest frequency you wish to capture ... for example to capture a 1kHz signal your sample rate must be at least 2kHz ... typical CD quality audio uses a sample rate of 44,100 Hz which permits capture of an input audio signal up to 22,050 Hz give or take ... you make no mention of sample rate - update your question telling us what you are using

Three factors determine storage needed to capture audio

- sample_rate
- bit_depth
- number_of_channels

for example lets use mono ( 1 channel ) with a bit depth of 10 bits (written to output file as two bytes that is 16 bits) and a sample rate of 44.1 kHz ... then one second of captured audio gives us 1 * 2 * 44100 bytes of data ... if you know the file size of your captured data and do not know say sample rate you can calculate it using above relationship

... perhaps you are plotting data which  must first get transformed in some way ... or possibly you are capturing audio intensity values at a slower sampling rate than the frequency of your input audio signal

Assuming the data points you show are your 10 bit audio samples, where one byte is 8 bits and so a 10 bit signal must require two bytes of storage per data point ... for example

```
637 shown above taken from a 10 bit signal which can vary from 0 to 1024
```

My advice is to generate a PCM output file which has a bit depth of 16 bits where you spread each input 10 bit data point across two bytes in this PCM file ... so the next step is to convert each 10 bit integer into a pair of two bytes ... pay attention to notion of endianness (little endian or big endian)   ...  normal PCM or WAV uses little endian ... this conversion will require performing a shift operation ... at a high level the first byte of output will just be the lower 8 bits of the 10 bit integer ... then do a bit shift to the right on that 10 bit integer which then becomes the second byte of output written to the PCM file

here is a 10 bit number (shown in binary)

```
0101011100   all 10 bits shown 
01  01011100 same data separated into two byte

most significant byte  01   least significant byte  01011100
```

to store that number in two bytes then populate the first byte by consuming the least significant 8 bits as in

```
01011100
```

then right shift the same original number `0101011100` by 8 positions ( 8 bits ) which becomes

```
01
```

and store it into the second byte ... above is conceptually what you need to do however in code say in c language it can be done in a couple lines of code

Audacity can render PCM audio and the file suffix has no bearing can be anything not just .PCM  ... File -> Import -> Raw Data  ... values you use for Encoding depend on how you treat the audio curve ... typically silence is value 0 then as the curve wobbles it does from positive to negative values ...  if your data varies from 0 to 1024 which is unsigned you may want to normalize it so it varies instead from -1 to +1 so its considered signed ... various such formats will work

You have two challenges : (1) validate your audio capture and (2) properly cut a binary file with the raw audio ... I strongly suggest you code up a loop to write a sin curve into a PCM file to nail that process before doing battle on capture validation

**Update** here is some doc http://www.mpja.com/download/31072mp.pdf

and a spec sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf
as mentioned in https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=292533.0

Looks like you are using the Digital Output which is a sound indicator ( comparator ) which gives either a high 1024 or low 0 depending on whether mic volume exceeds a threshold controlled by the potentiometer ... board may have an Analog Output which should give you the audio curve however you must feed it into a ADC ( analog digital converter ) to be fed a stream of integers

let us know how you get on ... this is very doable

Comment: Hi Scott! Very complete response. My first problem is that since I'm using a generic cheap microphone, I couldn't find any datasheet where the minumum frequency of the device is shown. Is there a way to measure how many points do I have per second? Regarding the shift operation that you suggest, you mean to perform a left shift from 10 to 16 bits, right? Why you say right shift instead?

Comment: Ok, so based on you last edit, you can do a simple equation in order to get the sample rate. I have 16 bits of bit depth, mono which is 1 as you said, and I can clear the sample rate according to the number of bytes that I get in 1 second, right?

Comment: yes ... just guess sample rate is 44100 Hz and run with it ... even if its wrong you will still get listenable audio